# Rails raw query for csv format, to be returned via controller

Tags: postgresql, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, pg

I was using active record to get my stories and then generate a CSV, the standard way as done in the rails cast. But I have a lot of rows and it takes minutes. I think if I could get posgresql to do the csv rendering, then I could save some time.

Heres what I have right now:

```
query = "COPY stories TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER;"
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query);
```

But the results are empty for this query:

```
 => #<PG::Result:0x00000006ea0488 @connection=#<PG::Connection:0x00000006c62fb8 @socket_io=nil, @notice_receiver=nil, @notice_processor=nil>> 
2.0.0-p247 :053 > result.count
 => 0
```

A better way of knowing:

```
2.0.0-p247 :059 >   result.to_json
 => "[]"
```

I suspect my controller will look something like this:

```
format.csv { send_data raw_results }
```

This works for normal queries, I just can't figure out the SQL syntax to have the CSV results returned to rails.

**UPDATE**

Got the CSV export from 120000 msec down to 290 msec

My model:

```
def self.to_csv(story_ids)

    csv  = []
    conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection
    conn.copy_data("COPY (SELECT * FROM stories WHERE stories.id IN (#{story_ids.join(',')})) TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, FORCE_QUOTE *, ESCAPE E'\\\\');") do
      while row = conn.get_copy_data
        csv.push(row)
      end
    end
    csv.join("\r\n")
  end
```

My controller:

```
send_data Story.to_csv(Story.order(:created_at).pluck(:id))
```

Comment: Is there any way to `send_data` straight from DB? I mean, without saving it to the `csv` Array?

Comment: @FernandoFabreti Sounds like the copy_data function returns rows which need to be joined together into one file. I don't think theres any way of combining the rows without some sort of variable assignment. You could probably use a string from the beginning instead and append in the loop. Would be interested in the performance diff.

Comment: I had to change `csv.join("\r\n")` to `csv.join("\n")` to get it to produce the rows correctly. It was originally adding an extra newline. Not sure if this will affect other non-*nix machines...

Comment: @penner Worked like a charm for me too, thanks to your update! Two quick questions, though: 

1. What about scenarios when a row is generated by multiple complex AR queries involving associations? How do we then generate a single SQL query and pass it in the above example? 

2. While it surely impacts performance in terms of time, does it also impact memory used by the operation?

Comment: @FernandoFabreti I ended up wrapping the answer into Enumerator that I pass to `self.response_body` as used [here](https://coderwall.com/p/kad56a/streaming-large-data-responses-with-rails). The linked example is incomplete and needs `lines << "#{row.length.to_s(16)}\r\n"` before yielding a row for a chunked response to work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

AFAIK you need to use the [`copy_data`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection%3acopy_data) method on the underlying PostgreSQL database connection for this:

> **- (Object) copy_data(sql)**
>
> call-seq:
>
> ```
> conn.copy_data( sql ) {|sql_result| ... } -> PG::Result
> ```
>
> Execute a copy process for transferring [sic] data to or from the server.
>
> This issues the SQL `COPY` command via `#exec`. The response to this (if there is no error in the command) is a `PG::Result` object that is passed to the block, bearing a status code of PGRES_COPY_OUT or PGRES_COPY_IN (depending on the specified copy direction). The application should then use `#put_copy_data` or `#get_copy_data` to receive or transmit data rows and should return from the block when finished.

And there's even an example:

```
conn.copy_data "COPY my_table TO STDOUT CSV" do
  while row=conn.get_copy_data
    p row
  end
end
```

ActiveRecord's wrapper for the raw database connection doesn't know what `copy_data` is but you can use [`raw_connection`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/AbstractAdapter.html#method-i-raw_connection) to unwrap it:

```
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection
csv  = [ ]
conn.copy_data('copy stories to stdout with csv header') do
  while row = conn.get_copy_data
    csv.push(row)
  end
end
```

That would leave you with an array of CSV strings in `csv` (one CSV row per array entry) and you could `csv.join("\r\n")` to get the final CSV data.

Comment: Ended up having to use a different query, one which escapes the data better. conn.copy_data("COPY stories TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, FORCE_QUOTE *, ESCAPE E'\\\\');"). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This answer builds up on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21127068/673826) provided by @mu-is-too-short, but without a temporary object using [streaming](https://coderwall.com/p/kad56a/streaming-large-data-responses-with-rails) instead.

```
headers['X-Accel-Buffering'] = 'no'
headers["Cache-Control"] = 'no-cache'
headers["Transfer-Encoding"] = 'chunked'
headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv; charset=utf-8'
headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="data.csv"'
headers.delete('Content-Length')
sql = "SELECT * FROM stories WHERE stories.id IN (#{story_ids.join(',')})"
self.response_body = Enumerator.new do |chunk|
  conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection
  conn.copy_data("COPY (#{sql.chomp(';')}) TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, RCE_QUOTE *, ESCAPE E'\\\\');") do
    while row = conn.get_copy_data
      chunk << "#{row.length.to_s(16)}\r\n"
      chunk << row
      chunk << "\r\n"
    end
    chunk << "0\r\n\r\n"
  end
end
```

You can also use `gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(Stream.new(chunk))` and `gz.write row` with a class akin to

```
class Stream
  def initialize(block)
    @block = block
  end
  def write(row)
    @block << "#{row.length.to_s(16)}\r\n"
    @block << row
    @block << "\r\n"
  end
end
```

And remember `headers['Content-Encoding'] = 'gzip'`. See also [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mlt/5988c3c3fd61858d13bd7c25891b9ecf).