# How to correctly handle character encoding when using Postgresql's copy_data function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv, encoding, character-encoding

In my Rails app, I managed to stream large CSV files directly from Postgres based on solutions mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126317/rails-raw-query-for-csv-format-to-be-returned-via-controller). My working code looks somewhat like so:

```
query = <A Long SQL Query String>
response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"
response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv; charset=utf-8"
response.headers["Content-Disposition"] =
     %(attachment; filename="#{csv_filename}")
response.headers["Last-Modified"] = Time.now.ctime.to_s
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection

conn.copy_data("COPY (#{query}) TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, FORCE_QUOTE *, ESCAPE E'\\\\');") do
    while row = conn.get_copy_data
      response.stream.write row
    end
  end
   response.stream.close
end
```

Some of the columns (`VARCHAR`) being queried have values as either English or Chinese strings. The CSV file resulting from the above code doesn’t show the Chinese characters as is. Instead, I get something like this:

> å¤§å¤§ æ–‡æ–‡

Am I supposed to change the way I’m using the `copy_data` function, or is there something I could do to the CSV file to solve this? I’ve tried saving the file as UTF-8 `.txt` file, as well as trying the `convert_to` function mentioned in the `copy_data` documentation, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This depends of the original encoding included in the CSV file.

Do this on Linux :

```
file -i you_file
```

Are you sure it's not UTF-16 or GB 18030 ?
And also in what kind of encoding is setup your database ?

do a \l in psql to see this.

Comment: Thank you for the help, @Hervé Piedvache. I've added an answer that solves the given problem.

Answer (score 0):

So it boiled down to my MS Excel not being able to render the Chinese chars correctly. On MacOS, opening the same `.csv` file using the Numbers app (or even Atom, for that matter) resolved this issue for me.